# What's the difference between Box layout model and Sliver layout model (BoxConstraints and SliverConstraints) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Having looked at some of the Flutter documentation, I'm still confused about the differences between the Box- and Sliver- protocols (i.e. BoxConstraints and SliverConstraints).

What are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- BoxConstraints are 2d related to a widget. They defines min/max width/height, and the constrained widget can pick any matching size.

They are linked to RenderBoxes, which are for the most part a one time render, until something they depends on change. Be it the size of their child, or some parameters.

- Slivers are 1d related to a scrollable element. It represents the dimension and position on the main axis of an item within a `Scrollable`

Slivers directly depends form the scroll variables. Implying that when the scroll offset change, slivers are recomputed.